# input box to populate excel formulas in a file

Tags: python, excel

I would like to create a Python script which would open the csv (or xls) file and with an input box I could copy and paste the Excel formula to the specific row...then apply this to the rest of the empty rows in that column. To help visualize it here is an example

```
DATA, FORMULA
001,  [here would be inserted the formula]
002,  [here would be populated the amended formula]
003,  [here would be populated the amended formula]
004,  [here would be populated the amended formula]
```

So, the idea is to have a script, which would get me the input box asking
- from which row you want to start? | answer = B2
- what formula you want to populat there? | "=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)"

...and then it will populate the formula in the B2 column and auto populate the next B3, B4, B5 and B6, where the formula is adjustusted to the specific cell. The reason why I want to do this is the fact I deal with large excel files which very often crash on my computer, so I would like to execute it without running Excel itself.

I did some research adn xlwt probably is not capable to do this. Could you please help me to find the solution how should I do this? I would appreciate any ideas and guidance from you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you want to do can't be done without implementing a part of the spreadsheet program (Excel) in your code. There are no shortcuts there.

As for the file format, Python can deal natively with the CSV files, but I think you'd have trouble importing raw formulas (as opposed to numeric or textual content) from CSV into Excel itself.

Since you are already into Python, maybe it would be a better idea to move you logic from the spreadsheet into the program: use Excel or other spreadsheet program to input your data, just the numbers, and use your script not to modify the sheet, but to effect the calculations you need  - maybe storing the data in a SQL database (Python s built-in SQLite will perform nicely for a single user app like in this case) - and output just the calculated numbers to a spreadsheet file, or maybe, generate your intend charts directly from Python using matplotlib.

That said, what you are asking *can* be done from Python - but it might lead to more and more complications on your general workflow as your dataset grows -

Hre - these helper functions will allow you to convert from the Excel cell naming convention to numbers and vice-versa - so that you can have the numeric indices with which to operate in the Python programing.

Parsing the formula typed in to extract the cell - addresses, is no easy-deal, however

- rendering them back into the formula, after the numeric indices are adjusted should be a lot easier). I'd suggest you to hard-code your formula in the script, instead of allowing for the input of any possible formula.

  def parse_num(address):
      x = ""
      for chr in (address):
          if chr.isdigit():
              x += chr
      return int(x) - 1

  def parse_col(address):
      x = 0
      for chr in address:
          if chr.isdigit():
              break
          x = x * 26 + (ord(chr.upper()) - ord("A"))
      return x

  def render_address(col, row):
      base = 26
      power = col // base
      col_letters = ""
      tmp_col = col
      for p in xrange(power,  -1, -1):
          dig = tmp_col // (base ** p)
          letter = chr(dig + ord("A"))
          col_letters += letter
          tmp_col %= base ** p
      return col_letters + str(row + 1)

Now, if you are willing to do your work in Python, just have your data input as CSV and use a small python program to get your results,instead of trying to fit them in a spreadsheet - for the formula above `COUNTIF(A:A,A2)` Basically, you want to count how many other rows have the first column as this row -  for 750000 data positions, it is a piece of cake in Python - (it starts to get tougher if all data won't fit in RAM  - but that would happen with about 100 million data points in a 2GB machine - at that point you can still fit everything in RAM resorting to specialized structures- above that it would start to need some more logic, which would be a few lines long using SQLIte as I mentioned above.

Now, the code for, given a CSV file with one column of data produce a second CSV file, where the second column contains the total of occurrences of the number in the first column:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

data_count = Counter()
with open("data.csv", "rt") as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    # skip header:
    reader.next()
    for row in reader():
        data_count[int(row[0])] += 1

# everything is accounted for now - output the result:
with open("data.csv", "rt") as input_file, open("counted_data.csv", "wt") as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    header = reader.next()
    header.append("Count")
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in reader():
        writer.writerow(row + [str(data_count[int(row[0])])] )
```

And that is only if you really need all of the first column in order on
the final file. If all you want are the count for each number in column 1,
regardless of the order they appear, you just need the data in `data_count` after the first block - and you can play with that interactively in the Python prompt and have results in fractions of a second what would take tens of minutes in a spreadsheet program.

If you have datasets that don't fit in memory, you just drop them in a database with a simpler script than this, and you still will have your results in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Hi Jsbueno.I don't insist on using Python.I'm also not the IT Professional-just a self-learner who knows a bit of Python.I thought it could be "doable" and maybe easy to do.However, after your post I can see it seems to be too hard for such a rookie like me.I wanted to have something which could allow me to work with large databases I work with (750k records).I would like to check it against smaller data sets using mostly Countif.When I do this in Excel it sweats a lot and often crashes.I am open for ANY solution to by-pass this problem, solution which does the job and is easy to implement

Comment: @mgunia :I am not saying you should not use Python: You should use it - what you should no do is try to use Python just to fill in- holes on Excel's functionality: Do whatever you need with your dataset directly in Python - that is my answer. A filter to select jsut certain rows, as that "countif" is a single expression in Python, and applying it to all rows can be done in two Python lines.

Comment: @mgunia: there you are, ac omplete example to get to your results (not pasting formauls to have Excel munching them, instead, doing the formaula calculation straight in Python)

Comment: I got the error in your code "can't assign to function call" in line 13. Do you know what's wrong?